# GCP VM not starting and impossible to relocate while terminated

Tags: virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform

Sometimes the CM is on a crowded zone.

```
The zone 'projects/path/to/project' does not have enough resources
available to fulfill the request. '(resource type:compute)'.
```

So I try to relocate to a less crowded region using the command

```
gcloud compute instances move [my-vm] --destination-zone us-central1-f
```

But the result is:

```
Instance cannot be moved while in state: TERMINATED
```

So I cannot relocate while not launched, and I cannot launch while not relocated!

Is there a way out this apart from waiting?

Answer (score 1):

have simliar problem.

rant:  have used DigitalOcean and other sevices and start to try gcloud. so disappointed. use DO for years and not any issues. might be bad luck. any way, stop use gcloud.